# How to get Signatures for Forums using SQL query?

Tags: 7, database

In a D7 site, I'd like to get all of the user [signatures](https://www.drupal.org/project/signature_forum) using raw mysql query . 
I've found a `signature_forum_post` table but could not figure out how to make a query that returns both user.id and signature text, so appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following.

`if ($account->id() && isset($form_state['values']['user_signature'])) {
    if (!$account->get('user_signature')->isEmpty()) {
      db_merge('user_signature')
        ->key(array('uid' => $account->id()))
        ->fields(array(
          'signature__value' => $account->get('user_signature')->value,
          'signature__format' => $account->get('user_signature')->format,
        ))
        ->execute();
    }
    else {
      db_delete('user_signature')
        ->condition('uid', $account->id())
        ->execute();
    }
  }`

Comment: Please note that I wanted sql query not php.